# Geocortex and ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, polygon, multipart, geocortex

I am currently working with a shapefile made up of multi-part polygons symbolizing zoning areas. Geocortex is a web-based service used to display your data. When I click on a larger polygon in ArcMap the polygon highlights neatly along the lines as a selected feature should. When I do the same through the Geocortex web-based data viewer, the polygon selected highlights from random points - creating triangular connection points - and not the line represented. I'll show an example in the attached image.

[image: Geocortex Data Viewer]

If anyone has experienced this issue, then how can I fix it?

Comment: I haven't used Geocortex for a couple of years, but I never noticed anything like that during the 3 years I was a Geocortex admin.  What happens if you attempt to select a polygon by clicking on an area that is excluded from the apparently selected areas?  Does it get selected or not?  Are you certain that there is not some other (eg, simplified) layer that is being selected, rather than the polygon layer you want to select?  Those background polygons... are they part of a basemap or part of a dynamically rendered layer?  It looks like they're in a basemap (judging by the antialiasing).

Comment: Is your polygon layer served out from ArcGIS Server as a map service, a feature service, or an image service?

Comment: This isn't a software-specific issue. It's just a matter of data scale. Everyone has a globe available, but since it's at 1:1 scale, it isn't very useful. The greater the map scale denominator, the more quickly you can access the data. If you have images constructed with 1:2000 scale data and vectors at 1:24000, it's expected that there won't be as many vertices preserved in display.

Answer (score 1):

Try re-creating the issue with your own polygon layer:

1. Create a new polygon featureClass,
2. Edit it in ArcMAP
3. Draw all sorts of polygons : Hourglass,  Islands, multi-polygon (user the cut/split editing functions). Draw polygons clockwise and anticlockwise.
4. Save all edits
5. Publish as a map service AND as a feature service
6. Consume the map Service in a test Geocortex map
7. Select : is the selection polygon accurately following your data?
8. Consume the same map service in Portal/WebAppBuilder or AGOL : can you select?

During your tests, condense to the simplest tests possible so you can isolate where the issue is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons for this behavior:

1. When a geometry is selected when you're zoomed out, and then you zoom in, the highlight may retain the approximate vertices that were returned when you zoom out.  To avoid this, you need to re-query the service when you are at the zoom level that you want to use.
2. The Geocortex web viewer will generalize geometries by default when there are more than 5000 vertices in a polygon geometry.  To avoid this, you must configure the viewer's Highlight module to not generalize, or raise its threshold above 5000 vertices.  (Note that this configuration is for performance reasons, so you may want to break you data up into smaller pieces if you regularly have polygons with thousands of vertices, and you regularly want to highlight those polygons)